# using linQ to mange SQL database created with SMO

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview, smo

I have a sample winform application that uses a data grid view to show some data form SQL database that will be created using a button.
the "create Database" buttun creates a database and a table in it using SMO.

so now I have some question about it:

**1st**: is this possible to use Linq to SQL with this type of databases? if yes please guide me to do it!

**2nd**:if is not possible to use `linq` with this database, so how can I show the tables h in my `datagridview`?

I am using the class belove to create database and table:

```
class SqlServerController
    {
        //ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection("MSSQLSERVER", "sysAdmin", "");
        private Server m_server=null;

        public SqlServerController (string server)
        {
            m_server = new Server(server);
        }

        public void AttachDatabase (string database, StringCollection files,AttachOptions options)
        {
            m_server.AttachDatabase(database, files, options);

        }

        public void AddBackupDevice(string name)
        {
            BackupDevice device = new BackupDevice(m_server,name);
            m_server.BackupDevices.Add(device);

        }

        public string GetServerVersion(string serverName)
        {
            return m_server.PingSqlServerVersion(serverName).ToString();
        }

        public int CountActiveConnections(string database)
        {
            return m_server.GetActiveDBConnectionCount(database);
        }

        public void DeleteDatabase (string database)
        {
            m_server.KillDatabase(database);
        }

        public void DetachDatabse (string database, bool updatestatistics,bool removeFullTextIndex)
        {
            m_server.DetachDatabase(database, updatestatistics, removeFullTextIndex);
        }

        public void CreateDatabse (string database)
        {
            Database db = new Database(m_server, database);
            db.Create();
        }

        public void CreateTable(string database, string table, List<Column> ColumnList,List<Index> IndexList)
        {
            Database db = m_server.Databases[database];
            Table newTable = new Table(db, table);
            foreach (Column column in ColumnList)
                newTable.Columns.Add(column);

            if (IndexList !=null)
            {
                foreach (Index index in IndexList)
                    newTable.Indexes.Add(index);
            }
            newTable.Create();
        }

        public Column CreateColumn (string name, DataType type, string @default,bool isIdentity,bool nullable)
        {
            Column column = new Column();
            column.DataType = type;
            column.Default = @default;
            column.Identity = isIdentity;
            column.Nullable = nullable;

            return column;
        }

        public Index CreateIndex(string name, bool isClustered, IndexKeyType type,string[] columnNameList)
        {
            Index index = new Index();

            index.Name = name;
            index.IndexKeyType = type;
            index.IsClustered = isClustered;

            foreach (string columnName in columnNameList)
                index.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(index, columnName));

            return index;
        }




    }
```

and also I have this code in the buttons click event:

```
private void btnCreateDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQL.CreateDatabse("BetaDB2");
            List<Column> ColumnList = new List<Column>();
            ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("id", DataType.Int,"" ,true, false));
            ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("name", DataType.NVarChar(50), "", false, false));
            ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("UID", DataType.NVarChar(200), "", false, false));
            ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("Pass", DataType.NVarChar(50), "", false, false));
            SQL.CreateTable("BetaDB2", "userha", ColumnList, null);



        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Entity Framework?

Comment: When I have a database I usually file datatable using an adapter the make the datatable the datasource of the DGV : datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @Dido
no, how is this possible? how can i use this?
i did not use it already